# How can I change the background color of input fields of text type when entering invalid values?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How can I change the background color of input fields using CSS of fields with text type when user enters invalid values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example to validate an email:

**HTML**

```
<input type="email" required/>
```

**CSS**

```
input:invalid {
    background-color: #FFAAAA;
}

input:valid {
    background-color: #AAFFAA;
}
```

You can use simple HTML to validate all these data types:

> tel, url, email, datetime, date, month, week, time, datetime-local, number, range, color

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/rvq4c/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid) pseudo-class:

```
input {background:#9F9;}
input:invalid {background:#F99;}
```

That code highlights invalid inputs red, and valid inputs green.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/uKAsUYA/1/). Just type any non-number in either of those inputs, and you'll see it change to red instead of green. This won't work for older browsers that either [don't support `input type="number"`](http://caniuse.com/input-number) or [css3 selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid#Browser_compatibility).